MYSQL - get last message from each conversation?
I saw some questions had been asked before, but the answers didn't work for this case.
The table User



Id
Name




1
A


2
B


3
C



The Chat table contains double-logged messages like this, where Side 1 is from the Senders perspective and side 2 is from the Receiver's:



Id
SenderId
ReceiverId
Message
Side
Created Date




34c1de57-11ba-4d34-b5a3-9e6a5511223b
1
2
Hello
1
2015-12-08 20:00


3c2c8aae-fd08-4879-96fb-6ac1c75d6b28
2
1
Hello
2
2015-12-08 20:01


60f91e53-7b8c-4cac-a394-e613fe39bcef
3
1
Thanks
1
2015-12-09 20:00


d74fa5f0-eb2c-4c32-9066-80e11e6160b9
1
3
Thanks
2
2015-12-09 20:01




Fiddle

Given a user id (ie: 1), I need the result to look like this:



Name
Side
Message




C
2
Thanks


B
1
Hello



How can I do it?

add some words to explain your result.  what is a "conversation"?  I'm guessing it is a distinct sender/recipient pair (in either order).  but then your expected result should have Side 2 for both conversations

So I get double-logging the messages, so you can easily lookup conversations for an ID from just one column... but if you're gonna do this, shouldn't the timestamps match?

What should "didn't work" mean? What have you tried, what exactly did not meet your requirements? Why don't you show your attempt in the question?

@JoelCoehoorn huh, I was assuming it wasn't double logging, that there were actually 4 messages.

what is "Side" anyway?

Also the expected results are showing the rows where the ID is the sender, rather than the more recent row where the Id participates in the conversation. This is in conflict with the question description. Which is correct? I think we might need a few more sample rows... extend the conversion between id 1 and one of the other users to include a second message, and show how it will impact the results. As it is, the question is not clear enough to answer properly.

Adding the read state has not helped... only added noise to the question. I'm reverting that edit.

when any message send will have double logging for tracking the status Read and Unread for sender and receiver that why I Need 2 record here . And the Side just for the frontend can detect which side , left or right when it loop the list data

@JoelCoehoorn give it a bit, maybe they will add some text to go with that

@PhạmMinhTân I understood that much. And you can infer a sender has always read the message, so that info is not helpful to solving this.

There's a conflict between the question text and the sample results.
The question text says to show the row for an ID that is most recent within each conversation. But sample results prioritize where the ID is the sender. The difference is the Side value should also be 2 for the "B" row.
If the sample results are correct, you want this:
WITH numbered As
(
    SELECT *
       , row_number() over (partition by receiverId order by CreatedDate Desc) rn
    FROM Chat
    WHERE SenderId = @Id
)
SELECT u.Name, n.Side, n.Message
FROM numbered n
INNER JOIN User u ON u.Id = n.receiverId
WHERE n.rn = 1
ORDER BY createdDate DESC;

If the question text is right, you want this:
WITH numbered as (
    select *,
        case when senderId = @id then ReceiverId else senderId end PartnerId,
        row_number() over (partition by least(senderId, receiverId), greatest(senderId, receiverId) order by createdDate desc) rn
    from Chat
    where @Id IN (senderId, receiverId)
)
SELECT u.Name, n.Side, n.Message
FROM numbered n
INNER JOIN User u on u.Id = n.PartnerId
WHERE n.rn =  1
ORDER BY createdDate DESC;

See them work:

https://dbfiddle.uk/A8ulAubN


Note with the revised data from the comments you get the same result for both queries:

https://dbfiddle.uk/R6omI_A1

Which again indicates you may not yet understand what you are asking well enough to be ready write code.

sorry for the question is not clear, the result I want like the facebook messenger [link]https://i.imgur.com/Ko5B6UM.png[link]
it will show list people send message recently with the latest message below their name

If that's the best you can explain, you might not understand the difference yourself yet. It's fruitless to work more on the code until you fully understand the problem.

https://dbfiddle.uk/4TzorNPe look like the second query is right for me in this case

@PhạmMinhTân Was missing an rn=1 filter. Check again.
